# Find condition by included words in JS string

Tags: javascript

I'm new with `JS`, I'm trying to figure out, what causes this result in condition:

```
if ((y1 == true || y2 == true || y3 == true || y4 == true || y5 ==true || y6 == true || y7 == true || y8 == true) && (n1 == false || n2 == false || n3 == false)) {
              document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "YES";
      } else if ((y1 == false || y2 == false || y3 == false || y4 == false || y5 ==false || y6 == false || y7 == false || y8 == false) && (n1 == true || n2 == true || n3 == true)) {
             document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "NO" ;
      } else if ((y1 == true || y2 == true || y3 == true || y4 == true || y5 ==true || y6 == true || y7 == true || y8 == true) && (n1 == true || n2 == true || n3 == true)){
             document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "BOTH TRUE";
      } else if ((y1 == false || y2 == false || y3 == false || y4 == false || y5 ==false || y6 == false || y7 == false || y8 == false) && (n1 == false || n2 == false || n3 == false)){
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "BOTH FALSE";
      }
```

if I have number of different words to find specific words in string by content with bool value:

```
  var input = "hello, yes and no"; // "hello, yes"; "hello no"; "hello"

  var i = input.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();    
  var y1 = i.includes("yes");
  var y2 = i.includes("sure");
  var y3 = i.includes("i want");
  var y4 = i.includes("yes i want");
  var y5 = i.includes("ok");
  var y6 = i.includes("oks");
  var y7 = i.includes("okay");
  var y8 = i.includes("okey");

  var n1 = i.includes("no");
  var n2 = i.includes("nope");
  var n3 = i.includes("not now");
```

this way result looks correct:

```
  if (y1 == true && n1 == false) {
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "YES";
  } else if (y1 == false && n1 == true) {
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "NO" ;
  } else if (y1 == true && n1 == true){
         document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "BOTH TRUE";
  } else if (y1 == false && n1 == false){
         document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "BOTH FALSE";
  }
```

1. if input `"hello, yes"` result is `YES`
2. if input `"hello, no"` result is `NO`
3. if input `"hello, yes and no"` result is `BOTH TRUE`
4. if input `"hello"` result is `BOTH FALSE`

   but if I want this result with number of values, in this case listed directly in condition with logical statement result is incorrect:
5. if input `"hello, yes"` result is `YES`
6. if input `"hello, no"` result is `NO`
7. if input `"hello, yes and no"` result is `YES` (Incorrect)
8. if input `"hello"` result is `BOTH FALSE`

I'm not sure if it is logical error or I've missed something, looks like `includes` also accepts `"ko"` as content of `"ok"`, so maybe this method is not the correct way to get desired result. Maybe it is easier just to split string and check each value. Anyway, I'm looking for the proper solution to find specific words in string, so any basic advice would be very helpful

Comment: Please please use `if(y1 && !n1)` instead of `if (y1 == true && n1 == false) {` - it makes it SO much simper to read

Comment: includes does not see ko the same as ok

Comment: Honestly, I do not get what is your question. As a suggestion, try `const isYtrue = y1 || ... || y8; const isNtrue = n1 || ... || n3;`. Then just to binary combination in if..else ladder. `(a && !b)`, `(!a && b)`, `(!a && !b)`, `(a && b)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Scott Hunter stated, while checking the absence of the string in your way, you're always getting `true`.

The right version of your condition is:

```
if ((y1 == true || y2 == true || y3 == true || y4 == true || y5 ==true || y6 == true || y7 == true || y8 == true) && (n1 == false && n2 == false && n3 == false)) {
              document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "YES";
      } else if ((y1 == false && y2 == false && y3 == false && y4 == false && y5 ==false && y6 == false && y7 == false && y8 == false) && (n1 == true || n2 == true || n3 == true)) {
             document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "NO" ;
      } else if ((y1 == true || y2 == true || y3 == true || y4 == true || y5 ==true || y6 == true || y7 == true || y8 == true) && (n1 == true || n2 == true || n3 == true)){
             document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "BOTH TRUE";
      } else if ((y1 == false && y2 == false && y3 == false && y4 == false && y5 ==false && y6 == false && y7 == false && y8 == false) && (n1 == false && n2 == false && n3 == false)){
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "BOTH FALSE";
      }
```

Notice that now there are ANDs instead of ORs between the `false` checks, and that's because *none* of them should be present.

Answer (score 1):

`(n1 == false || n2 == false || n3 == false)` will be true as long as at least one of `no`, `nope` or `not now` is not present in your string.  (See: DeMorgan's Law.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a function that validates and return the string.

**Idea:**

- Create list of words for `yes` and `no`.
- Now loop over these words and check for availability. You can use modern function like `Array.some` for this.
- Now you have 2 flags which needs to be validated. As binary permutation, you just have 4 combination,

  - 0 0 (*both false*)
  - 0 1 (*no `yes` word but `no` word exists*)
  - 1 0 (*`yes` word exists but no `no` exists*)
  - 1 1 (*both words exists*)
- Based on this, return necessary string.

---

**Few suggestions:**

- Most expensive part of a code is the part where human interacts with it. So keep it as simple/ readable. Having so many `||` conditions will confuse developer that takes charge after you go.
- Use meaningful names. `y1`... does not specify its purpose and anyone debugging will have to read the code to understand what is going on.
- If you notice your code, `y1 == false/true ...` or `n1 == false...` is repeated multiple times in same function. Its better to create a variable and store its value. Its simpler and you are not being redundant.
- Try to break your code in smaller parts. In your case, you can have following parts:

  - Interact with DOM. Accept value and set processed result.
  - Process accepted input and perform logic.

This way, your code will be more modular and scalable.

---

**Sample code**

```js
function processInput(input) {
  const yesWords = ["yes", "sure", "i want", "yes i want", "ok", "oks", "okay", "okey"];
  const noWords = ["no", "nope", "not now"];
  input = input.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();

  const containsYesWord = yesWords.some((word) => input.includes(word));
  const containsNoWord = noWords.some((word) => input.includes(word));

  if (containsYesWord && !containsNoWord) {
    return "YES";
  } else if (!containsYesWord && containsNoWord) {
    return "NO";
  } else if (containsYesWord && containsNoWord) {
    return "BOTH TRUE";
  } else if (!containsYesWord && !containsNoWord) {
    return "BOTH FALSE";
  }
}

const sampleInput = [
  "hello, yes",
  "hello, no",
  "hello, yes and no",
  "hello"
];

sampleInput.forEach((input) => console.log(input, processInput(input)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to have a look at this

```js
var input = "hello, yes and no"; // "hello, yes"; "hello no"; "hello"

var inp = input.trim().toLocaleLowerCase().split(/[^\w]/);
console.log(inp)
const y = ["yes",
"sure",
"i want",
"yes i want",
"ok",
"oks",
"okay",
"okey"]
const n = ["no","nope","not now"];
var found = {y:0,n:0}
for (let i=0;i < inp.length;i++) {
  found["y"] += inp[i] && y.indexOf(inp[i]) !=-1 ? 1 : 0;
  found["n"] += inp[i] && n.indexOf(inp[i]) !=-1 ? 1 : 0;
}
console.log(found)

if (found.y > 0 && found.n === 0) {
  text = "YES";
} else if (found.y === 0 && found.n > 0) {
  text = "NO";
} else if (found.y > 0 && found.n > 0) {
  text = "BOTH TRUE";
} else if (found.y === 0 && found.n === 0) {
  text = "BOTH FALSE";
}
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<span id="demo2"></span>
```

Comment: Hello, yes this looks much better and works exactly as I have described.  I have mark answer which explains problem in my logical condition, but this code looks  much useful of course